# Check if either of element is located

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver

I wanted to check , if element1 or element2 is present then return true.I use following code to check if element 1 is present.Now I want to check if either element with class name element1 or element2 is present, it should return true and finish the wait condition and move on to next line

```
driver.wait(until.elementLocated(by.className('element1')), 10000);
```

Basically something like below ? :P

```
driver.wait(until.elementLocated(by.className('element1 || element2')), 10000);
```

My example DOM looks like below

```
<div class="element1"></div>

OR 

<div class="element2"></div>
```

if anyone of div present, My coditions will be met..sometimes webpage generate only element 1 , sometimes it generate only element2, or sometimes both.

Comment: Provide more info: 1. Can you please share the relevant HTML DOM & provide the elements you want to check? Thanks

Comment: @Dev : Updated , thanks

Comment: @Vishnu  are you looking to check for presence or visibility? Element can be present and not visible

Comment: I am trying for elementLocated , this works perfectly for single element

Comment: would be great if you give code for element visibility too :D , I need that too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using a css selector like this:

```
by.cssSelector("div.element1, div.element2")
```

The comma is an OR operator in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution to your Question-

In Selenium 3.4.0 to induce ExplicitWait you can use multiple clauses with `ExpectedConditions` as follows:

### Java

```
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.or(
        ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("element1")),
        ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("element2"))));
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: Yes javascript please

Answer (score 0):

Finally got a solution that worked in Javascript. Many thanks to Moe for pointing in the right direction.

```
await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css('.element1, .element2')));
```